# How to return percentage formatted cells?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

The below code gets the sheet where the data is stored and takes the data using loops and also copies the formatting of each and every cell.

The issue is that it's not working with the cells that are percentage formatted i.e on the sheet the data is 8.7% and on my output email I get 8.766656454545454.

How can I fix this and get exactly what is in the sheet?

```
  function shrinkageEmail() {
    var getSheet = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxxxxxxx');
    var getID = getSheet.getId();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(getID);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SUMMARY");
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var recipient = 'cxxxx@google.com';
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    var subject = 'Morning Shift Shrinkage Report '+date;
    var schedRange = sheet.getRange("C16:J34"); 
    var body = '<div style="text-align:center;display: inline-block;font-family: arial,sans,sans-serif">'
    body += '<H1>'+ 'Shrinkage Report ' +'</H1>';
    body += '<H2>'
    body += getHtmlTable(schedRange);
    body += '</div>';
    debugger;
    //recipient = 'xxxxxxx@google.com';  // For debugging, send only to self
    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, "Requires HTML", {htmlBody:body})
  }

  /**
  * Return a string containing an HTML table representation
  * of the given range, preserving style settings.
  */
  function getHtmlTable(range){
    var ss = range.getSheet().getParent();
    var sheet = range.getSheet();
    startRow = range.getRow();
    startCol = range.getColumn();
    lastRow = range.getLastRow();
    lastCol = range.getLastColumn();

    // Read table contents
    var data = range.getValues();

    // Get css style attributes from range
    var fontColors = range.getFontColors();
    var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
    var fontFamilies = range.getFontFamilies();
    var fontSizes = range.getFontSizes();
    var fontLines = range.getFontLines();
    var fontWeights = range.getFontWeights();
    var horizontalAlignments = range.getHorizontalAlignments();
    var verticalAlignments = range.getVerticalAlignments();

    // Get column widths in pixels
    var colWidths = [];
    for (var col=startCol; col<=lastCol; col++) { 
      colWidths.push(sheet.getColumnWidth(col));
    }

    // Get Row heights in pixels
    var rowHeights = [];
    for (var row=startRow; row<=lastRow; row++) { 
      rowHeights.push(sheet.getRowHeight(row));
    }

    // Build HTML Table, with inline styling for each cell
    var tableFormat = 'style="font-size: 12px; border:2px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:center" border = 1.2 cellpadding = 1.2';
    var html = ['<table '+tableFormat+'>'];

    // Column widths appear outside of table rows
    for (col=0;col<colWidths.length;col++) {
      html.push('<col width="'+colWidths[col]+'">')
    }

    // Populate rows
    for (row=0;row<data.length;row++) {
      html.push('<tr height="'+rowHeights[row]+'">');
      for (col=0;col<data[row].length;col++) {
        // Get formatted data
        var cellText = data[row][col];
        if (cellText instanceof Date) {
          cellText = Utilities.formatDate(
            cellText,
            ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),
            'YYYY-MM-DD')

        }
        var style = 'style="'
        + 'color: ' + fontColors[row][col]+'; '
        + 'font-family: ' + fontFamilies[row][col]+'; '
        + 'font-size: ' + fontSizes[row][col]+'; '
        + 'font-weight: ' + fontWeights[row][col]+'; '
        + 'background-color: ' + backgrounds[row][col]+'; '
        + 'text-align: ' + horizontalAlignments[row][col]+'; '
        + 'vertical-align: ' + verticalAlignments[row][col]+'; '
        +'"';
        html.push('<td ' + style + '>'
                  +cellText
                  +'</td>');
      }
      html.push('</tr>');
    }
    html.push('</table>');

    return html.join('');
  }
```

Comment: Can you add an example input table that this code should process. Text-only, as code block, would be fine. Thank you.

Comment: Here is the link to the sample sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R3jQEhR_A7tdzYaj3QKUWZWUhIGl-DnMHmn1ihioFi8/edit?usp=sharing